# DB2. Select all columns in a table that contains a value

Tags: db2

I would like to find all column names in a table that contains a value in any given record.

I.e All columns that contains a string in the record value. 
'%ABC%' or '%QAW%' or '%IGH%'

If possible give me all the tables and columns in a DB schema, so I do not have to query ever table manually

**2016-06-15**

So I got a little further, I can now get all the values from each column in each row in each table. Now I need to see if that value ( v_value ) exist in a list of airport codes. i.e ['LAS','LAX','BIL']
I have all the airports in a table that I want to read into and array.

I am having trouble with creating that array and getting the data into it. 
Here is what I have so far. 
Look at the TODO's

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CMSDB"."TEST1"
()
LANGUAGE SQL

SPECIFIC SQL3
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE v_tabschema VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE v_tabname VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE v_colname VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE v_airport VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE v_stmt VARCHAR(3000);
DECLARE V_SQL VARCHAR(3000);
DECLARE v_value VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE v_stmt2 STATEMENT;
DECLARE v_value_cursor CURSOR FOR v_stmt2;

DECLARE v_airport_cursor CURSOR FOR select IDX from CMSDB.AIRPORTS;
DECLARE syscat_cursor CURSOR FOR select trim(tabschema), tabname, colname from cmsdb.syscat.columns where tabname = 'ACCTGROUP' and  tabschema = 'CMSDB' and TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR' and colname not in ('CHGDATE','CHGPAGE','CHGPROG','CHGTYPE','CHGUSER','CREATEDATETIME','CREATEDBYID','REC_ID');


  open v_airport_cursor;
        FETCH FROM v_airport_cursor INTO v_airport;
        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
          call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_airport);

             -- TODO Add each value to a list, arryalist that can be used to check if the v_value is in the list. 

          FETCH FROM v_airport_cursor INTO v_airport;
        END WHILE;

  close v_airport_cursor;

  OPEN syscat_cursor; 
        FETCH FROM syscat_cursor INTO v_tabschema, v_tabname, v_colname;
        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
                --call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_tabschema || ' ' || v_tabname || ' ' || v_colname);
                SET v_stmt = 'select ' || v_colname || ' from ' || v_tabschema || '.' || v_tabname;
                --call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_stmt);
                PREPARE v_stmt2 FROM v_stmt;
                OPEN v_value_cursor;
                        FETCH FROM v_value_cursor INTO v_value;
                        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
                                -- TODO 
                                --IF ( airportList contains v_value) THEN
                                        --call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_value);
                                --END IF;
                        FETCH FROM v_value_cursor INTO v_value;
                        END WHILE;
                CLOSE v_value_cursor;
                FETCH FROM syscat_cursor INTO v_tabschema, v_tabname, v_colname;
        END WHILE;
  close syscat_cursor;
 END P1
```

Comment: All "columns that contain a value"  or all **column names* that match a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sysibm.syscolumns`:

```
select colname
from sysibm.syscolumns
where tbname = 'XX' and
      (name like %ABC%' or name like '%QAW%' or name like '%IGH%');
```

Comment: Sorry i probably did not explain correctly.
I want to find all the columns that have a value in any given record.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a cursor over SYSTABLES that returns all the tables in the system.  Then have another cursor that returns all the column names in a given table.  Once you have those, you can build a dynamic statement that checks all the columns in a given table for the value you are looking for.  Fetch the next table name and do it all over again.

Obviously,  if you can narrow down your search to a particular schema or even limit the search to tables/columns with a particular naming pattern; you'd be better off.

Another technique, depending on your platform and version of DB2.  You might be able to do some sort of a bulk export to a set of text files.  Then use a tool that will serach the contents of those text files.

Comment: Hi Charles.. please see my updated question, I got a little further.